# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error (Python 2, sqlite3)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I can't seem to get past the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datascraper.py", line 352, in <module>
    URL))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "WHERE": syntax error
```

It comes from the following code (line 352 marked):

```
Table = someSQLtable //Has columns (providername, [other columns], providerlink)
SQLDatabase = sqlite3.connect(someSQLDatabase.db)
DBControl = cursor(SQLDatabase)

Name = 'somestring'
URL = 'http://www.someurl.com/stuff/'

[...] # Random other lines

DBControl.execute('''INSERT INTO '''+Table+''' (providername, providerlink) 
    VALUES (?, ?) WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                                    SELECT * FROM '''+Table+'''
                                    WHERE '''+Table+'''.providerlink = ?
                                    );
352)                      ''', (Name, URL, URL))
```

For reference, the SQL commands wrapped up in the Python should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO someSQLtable (providername, providerlink) 
    VALUES ('somestring', 'http://www.someurl.com/stuff/') 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT * FROM someSQLtable 
         WHERE someSQLtable.providerlink = 'http://www.someurl.com/stuff/')
```

And my goal is to check if the table already contains the entry in question by checking if the freshly retrieved link (which is unique) to the table, then writing to the table if it isn't already there.

Playing with whitespace shows that the exception comes up for the last URL on line 352.

I've already tried modifying the input to another string to see if that works, changing the code to use Python's string ops (horror!), and having a drink. Nothing seems to work so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The INSERT statement has no WHERE clause.

If you have a UNIQUE constraint (and if not, you should create one) on the `providerLink` column, you can simply use INSERT [OR IGNORE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html):

```sql
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO someSQLtable(providername, providerlink)
    VALUES ('somestring', 'http://www.someurl.com/stuff/')
```

Otherwise, you have to replace the VALUES clause with a query:

```sql
INSERT INTO someSQLtable(providername, providerlink)
    SELECT 'somestring', 'http://www.someurl.com/stuff/'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT * FROM someSQLtable
       WHERE providerlink = 'http://www.someurl.com/stuff/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's different i sqllite, but normally you cant have a where clause on a values statement. Try something like:

```
INSERT INTO someSQLtable (providername, providerlink) 
SELECT 'somestring', 'http://www.someurl.com/stuff/'
FROM ( values (1) ) as T 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM someSQLtable 
     WHERE someSQLtable.providerlink = 'http://www.someurl.com/stuff/')
```

If ( values (1) ) as T is not supported, perhaps there is something similar to Oracles dual or DB2's sysibm.sysdummy1

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need the `FROM`: `INSERT INTO table(...) SELECT '', '' WHERE NOT EXISTS (...)` should work.

Comment: According to standard you have to select from something, but perhaps SQLITE loosens this.

Comment: Yes, take a look at the other answer.